# Java API for z3 opt?

Tags: java, optimization, z3

I am trying to integrate the [Maximization API](http://rise4fun.com/z3opt/tutorial/) in Z3  from the [unstable branch](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/unstable) to my current Java project.

But I realize that there is no interface for Java(it works for C, C++ and Python). Shall I add the corresponding interface by myself?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now added a Java API for the optimization features to the unstable branch.

Comment: [This](http://rise4fun.com/z3opt/tutorial/) mentioned about Python API for optimization. Is it ready to use? Is there any tutorial for z3py-opt?